# Creating a trigger to copy data from one column to another in the same table - PostgreSQL

Tags: database, postgresql, triggers

I'm interested in figuring out how to copy a row of data from an old column to a new column within the same table. This would be individually done during a trigger procedure, not something like `UPDATE table SET columnB = columnA`.

To try to clarify, `table1.column1.row3 -> table1.column2.row3`  if an INSERT or UPDATE statement is executed upon `table1.column1.row3`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have your trigger assign

```
NEW.column1 := NEW.column2
```